# Node, typeorm - I need to connect to Oracle without credentials

Tags: node.js, oracle, typeorm, node-oracledb

I am working with typeorm and Oracle with typescript, but I have the following problem when I want to connect.
Basically I want to use externalAuth but it tells me that the variable is read only, how can I solve it??

**Cannot assign to 'externalAuth' because it is a read-only**

````
import { DataSource } from "typeorm"
import { Empleado } from "./entity/Empleado"
import * as oracledb from "oracledb";
oracledb.externalAuth = true;
oracledb.initOracleClient({ libDir: 'C:\\instantclient_19_12' });
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "oracle",
    connectString: "xxxxx",
    database: "xxxx",
    synchronize: false,
    logging: true,
    entities: [Empleado],
    migrations: [],
    subscribers: [],
})```
````

Comment: Have you seen this blog about external authentication from Oracle? https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/node-oracledb-connection-samples-proxies-and-external-authentication

Comment: yes I have seen it but how do I adapt it to typeorm and typescript?

Answer (score 1):

From a quick test with the TypeORM sample app, setting `externalAuth` using the `extra` attribute in the project's `ormconfig.json` file like this seems to pass through the correct settings to node-oracledb:

```
  {
    "type": "oracle",
    "connectString": "localhost/orclpdb1",
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": false,
    "extra" : { 
      "externalAuth": true 
    },
    "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
    }
  }
```

Comment: ty christopher!